# Syntax Error & Function got undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

errors

```
controllers.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MenuCtrl' is not a function,  got undefined
```

I am working to create an cross platform app with help of Ionic framework using word press as back end, Following are the files with codes

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!-- Cordova is bootstrapped by ionic-platform-web-client, uncomment this if you remove ionic-platform-web-client... -->
<!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
        <ion-nav-view> 

        </ion-nav-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl:  'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'MenuCtrl'
        })

        .state('main.contentRecent', {
            url: '/contentRecent',
            templateUrl:  'templates/menuContent.html',
            controller: 'MenuCtrl'
        })

        .state('main.postDetail', {
            url: '/postDetail',
            templateUrl:  'templates/postDetail.html',
            controller: 'PostCtrl'
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/contentRecent');
})
```

Controllers.js

```js
 angular.module('starter')
 .controller( 'MenuCtrl', function ($http, $scope){
     $scope.categories = [];

     $http.get("http://bijay.sahikura.com/api/get_category_index/").t 
        function(data){

            $scope.categories = data.data.categories;
            console.log(data);

        }, function ( err){
            console.log(err);
        }

})


 .controller('PostCtrl', function() {
     //hello
 })
```

Menu.html

```html
<ion-side-menus> 
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-view> 

        </ion-nav-view> 

    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title"> खुला सरकार  </h1>
        </ion-header-bar> 

        <ion-content>
            <ion-list> 
                <ion-item ng-repeat="category in categories" menu-close  href ="#"> 
                    <span> {{category.title}} </span> <span class="badge badge-assertiv"> १</span> 
                    category.post_count}}</span>
                </ion-item> 
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content> 
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to reuse the same controller within your config as well as define a controller 'MenuCtrl' that is visible within the html in the app. In that case you are better off defining the function separately and reusing the function name wherever you need that function. For eg.

```
function menuCtrlFunc(http, scope) {
  $scope.categories = [];
  // other stuff
}

angular.module('starter').controller('MenuCtrl', menuCtrlFunc);
angular.module('starter').config(
  //....
  //....
  controller: menuCtrlFunc,
);
```

HTH